# NodeJS/JS - write colored text into file

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, colors

I was wondering if it is possible to **append text to a file (e.g. with writeStream) that is colored**.
There was a lot of information about how to color console.log text, but I wasn't able to find anything about colored text written into a file.

I've tried to use modules like colors or chalk and also adding nodejs color references (e.g. FgBlack = "\x1b[30m"), but always with the fs.createWriteStream() and no result.

Comment: Your only option would be to use RTF (Rich Text Format). Otherwise, all other text formats are text data only. But you can use a markup format like HTML to encode color.

Comment: Text files can't have any inherent colour information in them, they only contain text. You *can* write something which includes markup that provides colour information (such as HTML or symbols like `\x1b[30m`) but then it stops being plain text and you need the software reading the file to interpret those symbols the way you want. It's really unclear what you mean when you say ["no result"](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Is the file empty? Is the file plain text without the colour information? Does the colour information appear as text? Something else? See [ask]. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: @RudyMartin — They mention console.log as *counter* example. The question says — three times — that the goal is to write into a file.

Comment: @ControlAltDel -- yeah that makes sense, should've thought about that earlier, will try RTF though :) ty

Comment: @Quentin -- yes that makes sense after reading it ^^ mhhh no thats not what I'm looking for, presumably ControlAltDel gave me the answer I was looking for.
Sorry if things were left unclear, with 'no result' I meant that the colour information appears as text, so not the result I was expecting from it.

Comment: @RudyMartin -- No, just as Quentin already said, it was meant as a counter-example. I mean.... just read the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard text files contain no colour information and don't really have any mechanism to include any.

(Quick side trip to the world of *...but technically*: You can combine some characters (such as waving hand: ) with a modifier (such as light skin tone: ) to give a combined glyph () but that's not what you're looking for.)

There are data formats which are made up of plain text, such as RTF

```
{\rtf1\ansi{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss Helvetica;}\f0\pard
This is some {\b bold} text.\par
}
```

or HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Example document</title>
<style>:root { font-family: "Swiss Helvetica"; } strong { font-weight: bold }</style>
<p>This is some <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
```

and you could probably throw in the [control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) that are output by chalk and recognised by your terminal into that category.

However, at that point your text file generally won't be refered to as a text file. It will be RTF, HTML or whatever and you'll need to read it with software that can interpret that data format.

---

You tagged this question [logging](/questions/tagged/logging). You might want to look at [Colorize Monitoring of Logs](https://serverfault.com/questions/53894/colorize-monitoring-of-logs), a question on one of Stackoverflow's sister sites about tools which can colourize logs.

You can keep your log files in plain text and then add colour when you view them.

Comment: Thank you Quentin, will definitely check out RTFs, even though HTML seems much simpler.
Yeah I was thinking in the wrong direction, so it does not really matter that it isn't a text file anymore, but for those kinds of things, the other link you shared seems to be relevant.